# How to remove the Activity in the bottom of the Activity Stack?

Tags: android, limit, activity-stack

In my application I have about a dozen of Activities. However, most of these have some shortcut-buttons, so the user can start the most important ones from anywhere in the app. This means, that the user can just jump around the app., filling up the Activitiy Stack with Activities. I can't change this behaviour, because I need the history function the stack provides (so I can't just use the noHistory option).

Obviously, I'd like to do something against this possible memory leak. Is it possible to remove the entry from the bottom of the Activity Stack, if the stack's size is greater than a certain number? So the stack only remembers the newest X (e.g. 30) Activity?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Obviously, I'd like to do something against this possible memory leak.

What possible memory leak? Android will destroy activities as needed to reclaim memory. If the user BACK-buttons their way to one Android destroyed, the activity will be recreated with its original `Intent` and passed the Bundle you filled in via `onSaveInstanceState()`.

> Is it possible to remove the entry from the bottom of the Activity Stack, if the stack's size is greater than a certain number? So the stack only remembers the newest X (e.g. 30) Activity?

Not that I am aware of. Again, you should not need it.

Comment: Ok, lets say that my task has thousands of Activity states saved already in my task with onSaveInstanceState(). I know that this is an extreme case of course, but it seems possible to me if the user uses the app. for an extended period of time. Wouldn't all these saved instance states eat up a significant amount of memory?

Comment: @Scythe: Unless you are stuffing something huge into the `Bundle` for `onSaveInstanceState()`, the instance state should not be terribly large. More to the point, what you want (some automatic cap) is not possible, any more than it is in a Web app. So, you either need to redesign your app to avoid this history dependence (e.g., `FLAG_REORDER_TO_FRONT`), or you need to do your own history system along with `FLAG_REORDER_TO_FRONT`, or you need to pray that the instance state mechanism is robust enough to handle your scenario.

Comment: I see, thank you. I seems that I'll have to go with a custom history system with the reordering flag.

Answer (score 1):

History Stack will be managed by Android Runtime; you do not have to worry about that.

However, if you have launched an activity earlier and want to bring it to the front, you can do this by setting appropriate [Intent Flags](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setFlags%28int%29)(like ACTIVITY_FLAG_REORDER_TO_FRONT). That way you would not have duplicate Activities on the stack when not desired. Note that, this will affect the chronology/linear nature of history.